# Suggestions for a Linux distribution for a dedicated SFTP server

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, sftp

I have a desktop which has more than 16GB of memory that I want to dedicate as an SFTP server. Many people have suggested that I install Linux, so I have decided to go with Linux. I am puzzled and unable to judge which distribution to install. I have no ideas or exposure to Linux before. Are there any suggestions to help me meet my requirement?

Comment: Are you trying to turn the desktop into a dedicated SFTP server? Or a shared system where users download files from an SFTP server? Your description is not clear.

Comment: Yes a dedicated SFTP server

Comment: Try http://www.archlinux.org/

Comment: SFTP or FTPS? SSH's SFTP protocol is not related to ftp+ssl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expect this SFTP server to be long-lived, pick a "long term support" version for a distro.  Many of the popular desktop distros (e.g., Fedora, most Ubuntu) stop receiving updates after a relatively short amount of time (e.g., a bit over a year after initial release).

So, the big "long term support" distros are the Red Hat Enterprise Linux-derived [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/) which tends to be more server/enterprise focused, and [Ubuntu LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS), which, happily, coincides with the current Ubuntu release, version 12.04 (codenamed Precise Pangolin).  Much as I live CentOS, Ubuntu is probably a bit friendlier to new users, and has extensive [community support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/) and [various](http://ubuntuforums.org/) [forums](https://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for SFTP, pretty much any distro will work.